# Spring convert localtime to UTC

Tags: java, spring, time

I have many clients, each in a different time zone. I want that once a client calls my API and passes localtime, the localtime will be converted to UTC time on my server.

Reason for that is that I want to save the UTC time to database using Spring JPA, I cannot save it's local time becuase it will be wrong.

What do you suggest?

```
import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.time.LocalDate;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/datetime/")
final class DateTimeController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "date", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void processDate(@RequestParam("date") LocalDate date) {
        // convert the LocalTime to UTC and save to DB
    }
}
```

Comment: `LocalTime` does not contain time zone information. You should probably use something like [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html)

Comment: You need to know the client’s time zone to do that. Can you get it somehow? There are some SO questions already on how to do that; search if you need input.